# Why does enable_if not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-traits

Can someone please help me to understand why the following code

1) does not cause an `error: redefinition of 'foo'`

2) why it outputs `T` and not `A&`

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class A{};

template< typename T >
void foo( T&& )
{
   std::cout << "T" << std::endl;
}

template< typename A_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A&>::type > >
void foo( A_t&& )
{
   std::cout << "A&" << std::endl;
}

template< typename A_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A>::type > >
void foo( A_t&& )
{
   std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
  A a;
  foo( a );
}
```

Comment: `std::enable_if` expects a boolean value, not a type. since you are not using `typename` before `std::is_same`, the compiler assumes it's a value, but probably fails to interpret it as such, and so it falls back to the first definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is "because you are not using `enable_if_t` correctly".

The pattern is

```
template< typename A_t, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A&>::value > >
```

Notes:

1. `typename =` introduces an unnamed type template parameter.
2. You need `::value`, not `::type` to pass to `std::enable_if_t`.

Once you use the correct pattern, you get a redefinition error for the second and third definitions (because you cannot overload on a default template parameter alone).

For the code as it stands now, the substitution always fails for the second template parameter, because `std::enable_if_t` wants a non-type boolean argument and `std::is_same<A_t, A&>::type` is a type. Since there are no valid instantiations of these templates, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Might be useful to mention `is_same_v` as the logical counterpart to `enable_if_t`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `std::enable_if_t` incorrectly.  Also the enabled definitions have to match the primary template.  Therefore you could enable_if on the return type.  Unsurprisingly the definition is ambiguous now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};

template< typename T >
void foo( T&& )
{
    std::cout << "T" << std::endl;
}

template< typename A_t >
std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A&>::value >
foo( A_t&& )
{
    std::cout << "A&" << std::endl;
}

template< typename A_t >
std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A>::value >
foo( A_t&& )
{
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    foo( a );
}
```

Why are you not just overloading `foo` for `A&&` and `A`?

Comment: The different `foo`s are overloads, not specialisations, so they are their own primary templates.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler prefers:

```
template< typename T >
void foo( T&& )
{
   std::cout << "T" << std::endl;
}
```

Over:

```
template< typename A_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A&>::type>>
void foo( A_t&& )
{
   std::cout << "A&" << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
template< typename A_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A>::type>>
void foo( A_t&& )
{
   std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
```

Because the later two overloads introduce [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

As already being stated in other answers, the application of `std::enable_if` is not correct. In order to apply [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) you have to alter your code in one of the following ways:

### Option 1:

```
template< typename A_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A&>::value>* = nullptr>
void foo( A_t&& )
{
   std::cout << "A&" << std::endl;
}

template< typename A_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A>::value>* = nullptr>
void foo( A_t&& )
{
   std::cout << "A" << std::endl; 
}
```

### Option 2:

```
template< typename A_t>
std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A&>::value>
foo( A_t&& )
{
   std::cout << "A&" << std::endl;
}

template< typename A_t>
std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A>::value>
foo( A_t&& )
{
   std::cout << "A" << std::endl; 
}
```

Now once you've alter your code in one of the options illustrated above, you'll get an ambiguity compile error cause overload resolution cannot choose between `template<typename A_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<A_t, A&>::value>* = nullptr> void foo(A_t&&)` and `template<typename T> void foo(T&&)`.

Once you get rid of the ambiguous call (i.e., get rid of `template<typename T> void foo( T&& )`) the code will compile and run and `template< typename A_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A_t, A&>::value>>
void foo( A_t&& )` is going to be choosen due to forwarding reference collapsing rules:

- A& & becomes A&
- A& && becomes A&
- A&& & becomes A&
- A&& && becomes A&&

In your case `a` is an `lvalue` thus `A_t` will be deduced to `A&` and bulls-eye first overload is preferred due to SFINAE.